# How to make a Java TreeMap be sorted by some comparator?

Tags: java, comparator, string-comparison, treemap

I have a java TreeMap<String, Integer> (let's call it multiset for now, because that is what I am using it for), and I want it to be sorted by the string's length. What I mean is that for some code like this:

```
// Imports
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeMap;

class CompareLength implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String string, String string_2) {
        return Integer.compare(string.length(), string_2.length());
    }
}

// More lines of code ...
TreeMap<String, Integer> multiset = new TreeMap<>(new CompareLength());
multiset.put("abc", 1);
multiset.put("x", 1);
multiset.put("yz", 1);

for (String string: multiset.keySet()) {
    System.out.print(string + " ");
}

System.out.println(multiset.containsKey("xyz") + " ");
```

The output is: x yz abc true

I wanted it to be sorted by length, not completely change the comparator of the TreeMap!
How do I do this? I also want this to work no matter what the comparator is, the key type, the keys, the value, the value type, etc.

Note: I'm very new to java, hence the misconception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you realized, the `Comparator` passed to a `TreeMap` doesn't just specify the *order* of the entries, but also which entries are considered equivalent (i.e. those for which `Comparator.compare()` returns 0).

The conclusion is that you simply shouldn't return 0 for any two string values, unless you want them to be treated as identical (in your case that seems to mean that they are `equal`). A simple way is to use a Comparator like this:

```
class CompareLength implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        int result = Integer.compare(str1.legnth(), str2.length());
        if (result == 0) {
          result = str1.compareTo(str2);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to specify the order of entries without changing the TreeMap comparator?

Comment: Wait, would adding the real string comparison as the "tiebreaker" work?

Comment: @Pranav Not only will a tie-breaker work, it is required! Otherwise you can only ever have one entry for any string of a particular length. Just try it.

Comment: @Pranav: by definition the order of entries in the `TreeMap` is defined by the comparator, so no, it can't be changed without changing the comparator. And yes, you need a "tiebreaker" (not necessarily String.compareTo, but *something*), if you don't want all equal-length strings to be treated as equal.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73595839/642706) is correct.

We can further evolve that code to be neater, clearer, more concise.

The [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) class has handy methods for creating a `Comparator` implementation using a lambda or a method reference. Here we use both.

Do *not* use the [`String#length`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#length()) method. That method is based on the `char` type. The `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters. As a result, **`String#length` fails** if the string contains any of the characters beyond the [BMP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) in Unicode, that is, fails with any of the majority  of characters. Instead, use [code point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers when working with individual characters in Java.

We declare our map to be the more general interface [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) rather than the concrete class [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html).

```
    NavigableMap < String, Integer > map = 
        new TreeMap<>(
            Comparator
                .comparing( ( String s ) -> s.codePoints().count() )  
                .thenComparing( String :: compareTo ) 
        );
```

Define some sample data. We add a couple more entries than you had to show multiple keys with the same string length.

The [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V)) methods in Java 9+ are a short sweet way to define an unmodifiable map in a literals fashion. We pass that map as an argument to populate our `TreeMap`.

```
    map.putAll( 
        Map.of (
            "abc" , 1 ,
            "x" , 2 ,
            "b" , 3 ,
            "a" , 4 ,
            "yz" , 5
        )
    ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
    System.out.println( map ) ;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/vDD5JC).

> {a=4, b=3, x=2, yz=5, abc=1}

Comment: Ummm ... style errors.

Comment: @StephenC I don’t understand the comment.

Comment: Your example code has lots of instances of Java Style Guide errors / violations.  I think I counted ~20 places where a space should not be there.  I'll fix them.  (Feel free to roll back if you object ...)

Comment: I was about to add the `Comparator.comparing` version to my answer, when I was interrupted yesterday. Thanks for providing what I left out :-)

Comment: @StephenC Thespacesareverymuchintentionalonmypart.Itisnow2022with4kmonitorsandscrollingwindows.Noneedtoprogramlikeits1978with80columnterminalscreensandpunchcards. Use spaces; let the code breathe.

Comment: Well in that case: *Style errors*.  Because all of the Java Style Guides I am familiar with say that each one of those spaces should not be there.

Comment: @StephenC Styles can change. Perhaps there is a reason that IntelliJ offers *seventy-six* options for inserting a SPACE before parens, around operators, before left brace, before keywords, within parens/brackets/braces, in ternary operator, around type arguments, and other places.